# Making autofill macro more dynamic

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following question about an autofill macro.

First I tried to record a macro:

```
'Sub bbbbbbbbb()
'
' bbbbbbbbb Macro
'

'
    Range("I15").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I15:I45")
    Range("I15:I45").Select
End Sub'
```

Second, I tried to modify it to become more dynamic: I changed the code to as below (for example, if my data increase to 100)

```
'Sub aaaaaaaaaaa()
'
' aaaaaaaaaaa Macro
'

'
    Range("I15").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

End Sub'
```

The problem is it didnt apply to the end of my last data but is to very end of my excel worksheet, can anyone advise please? many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this maybe

```
Sub YourMacro()

    Range("I15").AutoFill Range("I15:I" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

End Sub
```

So you don't need to use the `.Select`

Comment: it should be Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, right? i change to  H then it work

Comment: possibly, how am I supposed to know :)

Comment: also, i have a question here, if the H column contains 2 table (which separate by a empty cell in the middle), when i perform macro, it applied to second table too (including the middle empty space), is there anyway to applied to first table only??? Many thanks.

Comment: I guess it is because it counts the whole column and it will applies to the end of the last cell that contains words, so is that anyway to modify it please?? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use but without `AutoFill`.

```
Dim lrow as long

'-->Determine the last row based on a reference row. In this case it's Column H.
lrow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
Range("I15:I" & lrow).Formula = "=Formula or Value you wish to autofill"
```

Hope this helps you get what you want.